# SQL (postgres) RETURNING data from multiple tables after an INSERT INTO / UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, sql-insert

Is it possible in postgres to return data from multiple tables after 1) An INSERT INTO, and 2) an UPDATE?

For example, supposing the following contrived example:

```
review             fit
------             ----
id                 id
fit_id             label
body
```

**1) How can I insert into the review table and return the respective fit data joined with the review data in the RETURNING clause?**

So, SQL to insert without accomplishing the desired result:

```
INSERT INTO review (id, fit_id, body) VALUES (5, 1, 'some copy') RETURNING *;
```

However, the desired result is:

```
id     | 5
fit_id | 1
body   | some copy
id     | 1
label  | some label
```

**2) How can I update the review fit_id and return the new fit data joined with the review data in the RETURNING clause?**

SQL to update the fit_id to `2` of review `5` without accomplishing the desired result:

```
UPDATE review SET fit_id = 2 WHERE review_id = 5 RETURNING *;
```

However, the desired result is:

```
id     | 5
fit_id | 2
body   | some copy
id     | 2
label  | some other label
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO review VALUES (...) RETURNING *
)
SELECT inserted.*, fit.*
FROM inserted
INNER JOIN fit ON inserted.fit_id = fit.id
```

That will get you the output you want. Pretty sure you can't return stuff from another table in an `UPDATE/INSERT ... RETURNING` statement.